# How to allow/deny http requests from other namespaces of the same cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

In a cluster with 2 namespaces (`ns1` and `ns2`), I deploy the same app (`deployment`) and expose it with a service.

I thought separate namespaces would prevent from executing `curl http://deployment.ns1` from a pod in `ns2`, but apparently, it's possible.

So my question is, how to allow/deny such cross namespaces operations? For example:

- pods in `ns1` should accept requests from any namespace
- pods (or service?) in `ns2` should deny all requests from other namespaces

Comment: How are you deploying OpenShift? If you are using ``oc cluster up`` or ``minishift``, the SDN layer required to provide separation isn't installed. A full OpenShift cluster install should.

Comment: @graham Someone edited the question and added the openshift tag, but the question was related to Kubernetes

Comment: Okay, worth highlighting then, is that one of the things you get with OpenShift is multi tenancy out of the box. This means namespaces (projects) are isolated by default and you don't need to go adding it on top of Kubernetes yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good that you are working with namespace isolation.

1. Deploy a new kind Network Policy in your ns1 with ingress all. You can lookup the documentation to define network ingress policy to allow all inbound traffic
2. Likewise for ns2, you can create a new kind Network Policy and deploy the config in ns2 to deny all ingress. Again the docs will come to rescue to help with you the yaml construct.

It may look something like this:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
 namespace: ns1
 name: web-allow-all-namespaces
spec:
 podSelector:
  matchLabels:
   app: app_name_ns1
 ingress:
 - from:
  - namespaceSelector: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would not be answer you want, but I can provide the helpful feature information to implement your requirements.

AFAIK `Kubernetes` can define `network policy` to limit the network access.

Refer [Declare Network Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/declare-network-policy/) for more details of `Network Policy`.

- [Default policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-policies)
- [Setting a Default NetworkPolicy for New Projects](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/managing_networking.html#admin-guide-networking-networkpolicy-setting-default) in case `OpenShift`.